# Mark all messages read in QuickBlox iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, chat, quickblox

I am developing an chat base application with the help of `QuickBlox`.

There is an Api that returns chat dialogs where the last sent message and unread-messages count comes.

My problem is to mark messages as read. For this i got the working code like

```
[QBChat markMessagesAsRead:arrMessages dialogID:dialogId delegate:self]; // arrMessages is the array of message ids
```

It works well but sometime what happens some of message gets skipped and it always comes as unread messages in `QBChatDialog`

So My question is what should i do to mark all messages of it as read.

Or

How can i get those particular skipped messages that are unread. As it call the api to get messages it give only last one not that particular skipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mark all messages as read just passing nil as the array parameter

```
[QBChat markMessagesAsRead:nil dialogID:dialogId delegate:self];
```

In that case ALL your messages should be marked as read

Comment: Is there any way in QuickBlox to get only unread messages like if i just missed 5 messages and that are not the last so can i able to only get those 5 unread messages.

Comment: @ Igor, with latest quickblox sdk for iOS updates it changes the way to request for markMessagesRead in `QBRequest` like this, `+ (QBRequest *)markMessagesAsRead:(NSSet *)messageIDs dialogID:(NSString *)dialogID successBlock:(void(^)(QBResponse *response))successBlock errorBlock:(QBRequestErrorBlock)errorBlock`. But if I pass nil in place of `NSSet` it goes into error. With following message `Error reasons:{
    code = "<null>";
    message = "Resource not found";}`